# Re: Touching your toes (not mentioned in 30)

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, strength

My mother could touch the heels of both hands on the floor up to the age of 89. She had short legs and a long torso. Is it likely that someone who cannot reach his toes has a short torso and long legs, compared with the norm?

Answer (score 15):

Being able to touch the toes depends mainly on two things:

- hamstring flexibility
- body proportions (relative length of legs, torso, and arms)

It is not possible to change body proportions, so, to reach the toes, someone with longer legs and shorter torso/arms will need to have more flexibility in the hamstrings. It is possible for anyone to reach that level of flexibility. See:

[image: Size matters]
[(source)](https://loveyogaanatomy.com/size-matters/)

**How is hamstring flexibility measured?**

In the hamstring flexibility test (also called straight leg raising test, or SLR test), the maximal angle of flexion of the straight leg is measured in a lying down position:

[image: Hamstring flexibility test]

The usual classification is:

- inflexible for below 65 degrees
- normal for around 80 degrees
- above average flexibility for 105 degrees or more

**What about age?**

Muscles tend to become shorter with age, however, maintaining flexibility is quite easy with a little work. Flexibility is much easier to maintain than to acquire. An old person, who has acquired flexibility when he/she was young, will need to spend a lot less time maintaining it, compared to a younger, but inflexible person trying to become flexible. That said, flexibility can be improved in any age, I have seen people in their 30s, 40s, 50s gain much flexibility.

**So, can I blame factors that are out of my control, for my inability to reach my toes?**

No. The reason is lack of training.

Comment: While this is a great post, it doesn't answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: I've edited my post to try to answer the question better.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but I wouldn't call it "likely" in the sense that "this is the most probable reason". The most likely reason is simply a lack of flexibility.

If one, over a longer period of time, works on their flexibility, most people (barring certain "disabilities") will be able to reach their toes, or even palms, the floor.